# How find the $x$ such that $\{|AB|,|BC|,|CD|,|DA|,|AC|,|BD|\}=\{\sin x,\cos x,\tan x,\cot x,\sec x,\csc x\}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> Find $x$, such there exist four points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ in the plane, such that
>   $$\{|AB|,|BC|,|CD|,|DA|,|AC|,|BD|\}=\{\sin x,\cos x,\tan x,\cot x,\sec x,\csc x \}$$

We have solved one case: There can't exist $x$ such that $$|AB|=\sin x, |BC|=\cos x, |CD|=\tan x,|DA|=\cot x,|AC|=\sec x,|BD|=\csc x$$

But there are $6!-1$ other cases. I think there must be a simple method for handling them all.

Answer (score 4):

Lovely question. Assuming there is a tetrahedron $ABCD$ with lengths of the edges given by $\{\sin(x),\cos(x),\tan(x),\frac{1}{\tan(x)},\frac{1}{\cos(x)},\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\}$, by the [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) the squared volume of such tetrahedron is given by (according to Mathematica)
$$\small\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{4}-x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{4}+x\right)
}{1152\sin^4(2x)}\Big(\cos(4x)-8\cos(2x)-1\Big) \Big(\cos(6x)+2\cos(4x)-\cos(2x)+30\Big)$$
and such expression, for $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, equals zero iff $x=\arccos\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ or $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

It follows that there are just two configurations to check through the triangular inequality and [Ptolemy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality), pretty simple.

Comment: Nice! Thank you you can love this question,so you there exist $x$ such condition

Comment: Nicely done. For a tiny bit more algebraic detail, I'll note that the key equation can be expressed as $$(2 c^2 - 1) (c^2 - c - 1) (c^2 + c - 1)  (1 - c^4 + c^6) = 0$$ where $c := \cos x$. Clearly, the first factor has roots $\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$; we discard the negative. The second and third factors should be familiar to fans of the Golden Ratio, contributing roots $\pm \phi=\pm 1.618\ldots$ and $\pm 1/\phi=\pm 0.618\ldots$; only $1/\phi$ is viable here. The final factor can be written as $1-\cos^4 x \sin^2 x$, which clearly has no real roots.